# How do I auto-reload a section of the page with jQuery without refreshing entire page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So there are a few things I want to do. I have a section of HTML that I would like to be displayed on the page by default (i.e. the first time it loads).

```
<div class="viewport">
        <ul class="overview">           
            <li><img src="images/1.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/2.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/3.png" /></li>         
            <li><img src="images/4.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/5.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/6.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/7.png" /></li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
```

However, upon clicking an icon I would like for this section to be reloaded as a snippet of javascript is updated.

The code for the icon is:

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/2.png" id="icon#2"></a> | 
<a href="#"><img src="images/3.png" id="icon#3"></a> | 
<a href="#"><img src="images/4.png" id="icon#4"></a> |
```

The JS snippet that is updated is:

```
var win_width = $(window).width();
var num_of_images = 2; // This should be changed to 3, when 3 is clicked, and 4 when 4 is clicked, etc.
```

So it should reload the 'viewport' div on the page only...not the entire page.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is it reloading?  Is it fetching new content from some where else or hiding certain content?

Comment: Well what's happening is with the jquery variable 'num_of_images' set to 2, the first set of HTML is only showing 2 of those images. What I want to happen is when you click 3, you see 3 of those images instead of 2. The same should happen with 4.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution. Check it out when you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(function () {

        var num_of_images = 2,
            showAndHide;

        $("img[id^=icon]").bind("click", function () {
            num_of_images = parseInt(this.id.replace("icon#", ''), 10);
            showAndHide(num_of_images);
        });

        (showAndHide = function (n) {
            $("ul.overview").hide() // hide this while we "do work"
               .children() // get children
                  .show() // show all children
                  .filter(":nth-child(" + n + ") ~ li") // get the next siblings of the nth child
                     .hide() // hide them
                  .end()
               .end()
            .show(); // show the parent list
        })(num_of_images)

    });
```

This is a "pending" solution. I have not tested this and I would be surprised if it works.

**EDIT**: Alright, I tested and fixed a few things and this seems to work.

Note that I attached a click handler to those `img` elements. So you don't need those anchor tags if you don't want them.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are looking to reload just a portion of the page with HTML content (no added JavaScript) then you could use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$('div#content').load('morecontent.php');
```

Comment: Suppose I wanted to hardcode the HTML in the jquery function? First question is, is there a load hit if I did that rather than loading a separate file? The second question is, how would I do that? Just chain the .html() function to that line?

Comment: if you want to hardcode the HTML, yes, use the .html() function

Comment: No need for an HTML function, the load function replaces that chunk of HTML for you.  Check for examples of load() online, or try it yourself.  Using google chrome's JavaScript console on one of your pages is a great way to experiment with jquery and figure out what will work in your situation, you can just type the jquery commands and see the results interactively.

Comment: Loading a separate file submits a new request to the server (using .load()).  If you hardcoded the content then there wouldn't be a request sent to the server.  If you are adding a lot of HTML I wouldn't hardcode it into JavaScript... another approach is using templating system to add an HTML structure into the page (see http://blog.jbstrickler.com/2010/07/jquery-templates-by-microsoft/)

Answer (score 0):

You want `$('.viewport').load('/url')` to replace the viewport' contents with the new chunk of HTML return from the server from /url. You call that load function once when the page loads, and again any time you want to replace the contents of viewport.  You might want to do some include type magic in whatever template language you're using to make it so that you can skip the initial load and render the initial page in one request instead of 2.  You trigger the load function in a change event or other kind of event on your page.

Comment: I am using no template language for now. Just straight html, css and jquery. So would I have to create a standalone html file with just that content there and load it like that? Also, the html file that is just for loading purposes, does it have a regular <html><body></body></html> tags?